# Adding data from one model to another in Sails Waterline

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have 3 models defined in Sails(NodeJS) given as a below

Model A:

- **id**
- name
- role
- etc.

Model B:

- id
- **A_id**
- name
- age
- etc.

Model C:

- id
- **A_id**
- job
- etc.

As given above, `ModelB` and `ModelC` have a foreign key mapped to `ModelA`.

Now, if the attribute `role` in `ModelA`  == 'B', data needs to be inserted in ModelB. Similarly, if attribute `role` in `ModelA`  == 'C', insertion to be made in ModelC.

Also, These child models have different attributes. So, once the role is mentioned, I need to either take in attributes of respective models or redirect it to the respective controllers to route the methods.
How can i achieve this?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Could use some clarification: you are considering how to create either a ModelB or ModelC corresponding to a newly created ModelA? Or does your ModelA already exist? Explaining a little what these models represent would likely help.

Comment: Also.. sails 0.12.x or sails 1.0? Any reason why you're using A_id instead of `A: { model: "A" }` to create a relation between A and B ?

Comment: Well, yes. All three Models do exist. I've created these in the MySQL & implemented CRUD
As an Example --> If ModelA.role = 'food', then send parameters to insert in ModelB. --> if ModelA.role = 'drinks', then same - must go to ModelB instead.
I hope this illustration helps.

I tried calling ModelB from ModelA as -- ModelB.create(params).exec(callback function), but its giving some foreign key error :
 user_student_FK is constraint name in MySQL(although column name = A_id
`Details:  { code: 'E_FK',
  invalidAttributes: { user_student_FK: [ [Object] ] },
  originalError: [Circular] }`

Comment: @lascort I actually created the DB structure & thought to keep it informative. ModelB has an attribute like : `A_id : { model : 'A', type : 'integer' }`. But after sending a POST request with params of `ModelA` and `ModelB`, i'm getting an error `"message": "[Error (E_UNKNOWN) Encountered an unexpected error] Details:  { code: 'E_FK',\n  invalidAttributes: { A_B_FK: [ [Object] ] },\n  originalError: [Circular] }\n",`

Comment: I think your association should not include `type`. `A_id: {model: 'A'}` should suffice. I don't know if that can cause an error though, I haven't seen or used it like that before.

Comment: @lascort -- I tried that too. But the error still persists. I'll provide a simpler piece of code below:
`if role = 'food' then --> console.log("Role Defined --> Teacher"); var foodDetails = {B_Id : createdUser.id, foodType : data.type }; console.log(foodDetails); //works fine, but still the error persists
ModelB.create(data).exec(function(err, createdFood){ if(err) --> return callback(err); //I think error is here
callback(null, createdFood);//this statement is else block, returning successful callback });` Apologies for the messy un-formatted code :)